# Django - Treat None as 0

Tags: python, django

In my django application, the database is read-only, which contains many IntegerField and DecimalField.

The problem is, those fields are NULLABLE.

My attempt was:

```
.extra(select={'field':'COALESCE(field_interested_in, 0}')
```

My question is is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

How about define a property?

```
def field(self):
    return self.field_interested_in or 0
```

Comment: This should help in representation but won't work if I want to sort by that field.